# NavigationView onNavigationItemSelected not working

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have been trying to get my navigation drawer events working but you guessed it, it wont. as nothing fires up each time i clicked on an item in the navigation drawer. I have also tried a couple of help on here but to no avail.

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_bg_fainted"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.airtimeflip;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private NavigationView navigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        /*FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        //adding event listener to the navigation view
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_manager,
                R.id.nav_atc, R.id.nav_buy_airtime, R.id.nav_send_money)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_atc){
            Toast.makeText(this, "airtime to cash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_buy_airtime){
            Toast.makeText(this, "buy airtime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_profile){
            Toast.makeText(this, "profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_manager){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Accoun Manager", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_send_money){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Send Money", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I have no error whatsoever from this and i pretty don't know where i have got it wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` and `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` together.

`onNavigationItemSelected` will work if you remove this line from your code:

```
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

but then you have to handle fragment transactions manually.

Comment: is there no other way to handle this other than the way you've specified

Comment: There is, but that might increase complexity,
You can add `addOnDestinationChangedListener` to your navcontroller and detect the destination and display appropriate toast etc.

Comment: i have used addOnDestinationChangedListener which seemed only to detect the destination you currently on which is not actually what i want. and i have removed NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController); and it working but i want only the selected item to be marked active not all of them as every item i selected turn green and doesnt go away

Comment: **NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItemId,navController)**  might also work

Comment: for more clarity you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761704/8258305

Answer (score 0):

This code works well for me.

hide this line

NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

and put the code commented below

```
your.package.name

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    public TextView txt_name;

    BottomNavigationView Bottom_Nav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_message, R.id.nav_notification, R.id.nav_account, R.id.nav_number, R.id.nav_website, R.id.nav_setting, R.id.nav_logout)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        //NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
/*
* Put this code 
* */
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                Toast.makeText(NavigationDrawerActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
                    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG ,"In Account");
                }
                if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
                    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG ,"In Log out");
                }
                DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return false;
            }
        });
/*
* Put this code 
* */
```

}