# Navigation drawer buttons are not working

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am experiencing a problem with my navigation drawer, for some reason the buttons are not working. Every time I click on any button the navigation drawer simply closes. This is my code below, please help. An example is when I click on the button associated with nav.homee No toast is created and the drawer simply closes

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_homee, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,R.id.nav_home)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main14, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id=item.getItemId();

    if (id==R.id.action_settings){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){


    int id=item.getItemId();
    if (id==R.id.nav_home){

    }else if (id==R.id.nav_gallery){
        String link="Check out the best taxi app in Zed! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chomba.haroldking.uta";
        Intent share=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"UTA share"));
        return true;
    }else if (id==R.id.nav_homee){
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"UTA standard is still under",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        View view1=toast.getView();
        view1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mdtp_transparent_black);
        TextView text=(TextView)view1.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CDEAF7"));
        toast.show();
        return true;
       // Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main14Activity.this, Standarduta.class);
        //startActivity(intent1);
    }else if (id==R.id.nav_slideshow){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main14Activity.this, Main7Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        return true;
    }
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}
Below is my xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"> 
 <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main14"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main14"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main14_drawer" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide the layout that contains the `<DrawerLayout>`.

Comment: @Mike M. I have provided it

Comment: OK, the layout is fine. Just wanted to make sure. Your issue is that when you use the Navigation component, by default, it handles the `NavigationView` clicks internally, so your `onNavigationItemSelected()` will not be called. If you'd like to handle certain items yourself, and to let the Navigation component handle the rest, you'll need to do something like is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761704).

Comment: It's worked, thank you very much