# How do I fix this error in navController MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Illegal State Exception error... I can't  understand...How do I fix MainActivity does not have a navcontroller?

I just got my code to compile and when I try to start the app I receive the error. I'm currently trying to setup Fragments for my class project. Not sure why I'm getting this output...

***Error:-***

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.instagramclone.MainActivity@6a5f3da does not have a NavController set on 2131362023
```

***My MainAcivity.java:-***

```
package com.example.instagramclone;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.example.instagramclone.ui.home.HomeFragment;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ImageView cameraToolbar = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.camera);

        cameraToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CAMERA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_home)
                {

                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment , homeFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                }

                else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.search) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***My activity_main.xml:-***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/white2"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/camera"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/bilbo_swash_caps"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Instagram"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/igtv"
                app:tint="@color/textcolor" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/send" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation">

    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***Error:-***

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.instagramclone.MainActivity@6a5f3da does not have a NavController set on 2131362023

at com.example.instagramclone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
```

Comment: Please post the code of `nav_host_fragment`.xml and `navigation_graph`.xml for us to review further.

Comment: Note that your code in your `onNavigationItemSelected()`, while unrelated to your exception, is absolutely going to cause you issues - you should never be doing a `FragmentTransaction` when using Navigation. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761704/1676363) for how to implement that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973), this is expected when you're using `Navigation.findNavController()` and `FragmentContainerView` together and trying to access the `NavController` in the `onCreate()` method of your activity.

`Navigation.findNavController()` relies on the fragment's view to already exist by the time it is called (that's why it takes the ID of a view where your fragment is located). However, when using a `FragmentTransaction` or `FragmentContainerView` (which uses a `FragmentTransaction` to add the `NavHostFragment` to your layout), the Fragment's view isn't created yet in the `onCreate()` of the activity. Therefore, `findNavController()` has no View to find and, hence, your error.

As per [the 4th comment on that issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment4), you can retrieve the `NavController` directly from the `NavHostFragment` (as while the Fragment's *view* hasn't be created yet, the Fragment itself has been):

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use this in your code if you are using the navigation controller

```
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment , homeFragment);
            transaction.commit();
```

instead, consider using this

```
Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(YOUR ACTION)
```

and consider checking this link [docutmentation](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50502269.html)
and for a tutorial for using navHost correctly consider watching this  [nav host documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Comment: This is a big problem and something that needs to be fixed, but is unrelated to the actual exception that is being thrown (which happens before any of this code is triggered).